# Open port on router to access from outside LAN

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, lan, portforwarding

I want to access my raspberrypi from outside my local network, in particular using ssh. When I searched for answers, almost all mentioned port forwarding. My understanding is a little thin, but I think I have forwarded the port. Instead of the standard port 22 I use something like port 2222:

```
ssh -p 2222 bla@raspberrypi
```

This works locally, but it didn't work when I tried it outside, and I found that port 2222 is closed. My impression was that port forwarding was synonymous with "making the port available outside LAN". How do I actually open the port for outside access? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your routers admin page, usualy at 192.168.1.1 (especaly cisco), sometimes is at 192.168.100.1. Another concern is that you have to have static ip from isp because there is a refresh rate which if you have the ip is resetting. You could open a port to the dynamic ip but it will be eventualy changed. I have tested this and it work until the ip changed.The default port is 22 but you could change it, here is a tutorial and explanation by [Eli the Computer Guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dmQnJRXbzEk). If you couldn`t port forward watch a tutorial on how to port forward on your router. I recommend because you have little knowledge in port forwarding that you should go with the default port. 
Keep Hacking. Good Luck :) !